# Swift Remove control characters from string

Tags: swift, barcode, control-characters

I have a Swift app that is scanning a barcode. The barcode sometimes contains a control character at the beginning which is not visible: \u{1D}

I use this method to strip the value from the string but I am looking for something more robust in case some other control characters come up or are inside the string and not at the beginning.

```
if(articleFilter.hasPrefix("\u{1D}")){
    let stringSize = articleFilter.count - 6
    finalArticleCode = String(articleFilter.suffix(stringSize))
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use extension to filter other characters except for the numeric.

```
extension String {

  func filterNonNumeric() -> String {
    return self.components(separatedBy: CharacterSet.decimalDigits.inverted).joined()
  }
}
```

```
var str = "\u{1D}01000000000010"
self.sampleLabel.text = str.filterNonNumeric()
```

The result will be:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Removing characters from the start and end is called *trimming*. And the control characters are:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nscharacterset/1416371-controlcharacters

So, like this:

```
let articleFilterNew = articleFilter.trimmingCharacters(in: .controlCharacters)
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe You can use Replacing String protocol

```
articleFilter = articleFilter.replacingOccurrences(of: "\u{1D}", with: "")
```

I think it will solve your problem.

Comment: Is there also a way to use replacingoccurenzces() with .controlCharacters? When I try

finalArticleCode = articleFilter.replacingOccurrences(of: .controlCharacters, with: "")

I get "Type of expression is ambiguous without more context" as error

Answer (score 0):

It is very simple by using trimming Characters

```
var str =  "\u{1D}01000000000010"

let filteredOne = str.trimmingCharacters(in: .controlCharacters)
```

Answer (score 0):

For Objective C, I have used the following code and it works

```
-(NSString *)normalizeText:(NSString *)text {
    NSString *normalizedText = [[text componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:NSCharacterSet.controlCharacterSet] componentsJoinedByString:@""];
    NSLog (@"Result: %@", normalizedText);
    
    return normalizedText;
}
```

For Swift, it is similarly something like

```
func normalizeText(text: String) -> String {
return text.components(separatedBy: .controlCharacters).joined()
}
```